# Excel: Move cell contents to comment

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm using Excel 2007.

I have a list of items and wish to take the information in the cells of one column and move it into comments for the cells in that column.

Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve manually cutting the cell content then creating a comment and pasting the text in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following VBA code will move the text values of the selected cells into the comments. It will only work if there arent any existing commnets

```
Sub Test()
    For i = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count
            Selection.Cells(i, j).AddComment (Selection.Cells(i, j).Text)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This VB script will not work for the entire range of cells - it will only work for the 1st cell in a range.

Comment: Have adjusted it to work on whole selection

Comment: Code didn't work in Excel 2007.

Comment: @Caliban: Works perfectly for me in Excel 2007.

Comment: Best guess (as I dont have the sheet you ran it on), was that there were existing comments in the cells which would break it (though trivial to fix)

Answer (score 3):

Refer to this [thread on ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=75759&page=2) for automated conversion of cell values to cell comments. Requires a certain level of savvy /w VB macros.

Answer (score 1):

I've expanded on the given answer, so that no comments are added for empty cells and to move rather than copy the text:

```
Sub Text2Comment()
    For i = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count
            If Selection.Cells(i, j) <> "" Then
                Selection.Cells(i, j).AddComment (Selection.Cells(i, j).Text)
                Selection.Cells(i, j) = ""
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```