# Excel: Move cell contents to comment in a certain cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to convert text content in a cell, into a comment in other cell (the one on the left). I saw [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/42182/excel-move-cell-contents-to-comment), and the code works fine but it puts the comment in the same cell the text content is.

Example:
I need the text in Column B to be a comment on Column A.

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells containing the data *(in your case the cells in column B)*

and run this short macro:

```
Sub CommentMaker()
   Dim r As Range, v As String
   For Each r In Selection
      If r.Column <> 1 Then
         If r.Text <> "" Then
         v = r.Text
         With r.Offset(0, -1)
            .ClearComments
            .AddComment
            .Comment.Visible = False
            .Comment.Text Text:=v
         End With
         End If
      End If
   Next r
End Sub
```

**Note:**  this will not remove the original data!